# Disable or non-accessible popup background area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html structure  :

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- data -->    
<div id="popup"></div>
    <!-- data -->
</div>
```

I am displaying my popup on page load , but at the same time I want to disable background area . My popup box is appearing on z-index , and rest background area should be non-accessible at this time .

How can I achieve this ?

I am using this css style :

```
#popup {
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(36, 35, 35);
    border: 5px solid rgb(5, 5, 5);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -402px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 600px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a div to cover the entire window.

This will not be enough though since a user might still use the keyboard to navigate in the background. You would have to iterate all the a/input/button/select elements on the page and add an tab-index attribute set to -1. When you hide the pop-up they should remove the 'tab-index' attribute.

The reason for the tab-index manipulation is also one of accessibility. A user that navigates through the keyboard will have a hard time navigating content inside of your pop-up if you let them navigate in the background.

So, how would we go about constructing this? Just to set you off:

Html:

```
<div id="popup" class="popup">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <div class="popupBody">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.popup {
   background-color:black;display:none;
   position:fixed;
   left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
   z-index:3000;
   opacity:0.5;
}
```

js+ jQuery for adding tabindex:

```
$('input, a, button, select').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
});
```

Note: Here the popup is the 'cover', with popupBody being the actual popup, uggly but working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mjfag/1

**An alternative would** be to use the JQuery UI module for modal dialogues. That does nothing for the keyboard-navigation though but if that is of no concern all the other stuff is already done for you.

Edit: After some quick testing with a newer version of jQuery UI it seems like they've started handling the keyboard to.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <div class="modalpopup">
        <div class="modal-backdrop fade in">//for background disable
        </div>
        <div 
            class="modal hide fade in" id="myModal" style="display: block;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>
                    Popover in a modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">
                    Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop,
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 560px;
  margin-left: -280px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}

.modal.fade {
  top: -25%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.fade.in {
  top: 10%;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.modal-header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-form {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 14px 15px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
          border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}

.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}

.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.modal-footer .btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-left: 0;
}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to completely cover the div: *#content*  with some other div.

**Here's the Complete HTML Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pop Up Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #EFEFEF;
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #enclosePopUp {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
        display: none;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #popup {
        position: absolute;
        _position: absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */
        height: 45px;
        width: 295px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        left: 500px;
        top: 250px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid #BDBDBD;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 15px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #D8D8D8;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #D8D8D8;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #D8D8D8;
    }

    #disabledLink {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadPopUp() {
        $('#enclosePopUp').fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $("#main").css({
                "opacity" : "0.3",
                "z-index" : "1"
            });
            $("#disabledLink").show();
        });

    }
    function unLoadPopUp() {
        $('#enclosePopUp').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#main").css({
                "opacity" : "1"
            });
            $("#disabledLink").hide();
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <a href="#" onclick="return loadPopUp();">Click here to show PopUp</a>
        <br> <a id="disabledLink" href="http://www.google.com">Google.com</a>
    </div>
    <div id='enclosePopUp'>
        <div id="popup">
            This is a pop up with disabled background. <br> <a href="#"
                onclick="return unLoadPopUp();">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```